# Asp.net mvc5 same action POST and GET in the same method

Tags: asp.net, post, asp.net-mvc-5, get

Can i send to the action method new record and then get the new id by the same method

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult _sendConfirmation'(string subject,string mail)
    {
        Some Code--Some Code---Some Code
        return Json(new { Success = true, id = newCreatedMailId });
    }
}
```

Getting the id by jquery

```
            $.getJSON('/Mails/_sendConfirmation', function (comingData) {

                alert("success" + data);
                jQuery.get('/Mails/_getNewMailSendConfirmation', { id: comingData }, function (data) {

                    jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');

                    jQuery('#myModal .modal-body').html(data);
                });
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Is your code failing in some way?  What happens when you *try*?  What *are* you trying?

Comment: i am getting this error in the browser Console:2:6133/Mails/_sendConfirmation Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Then the requested resource was not found.  What was requested?

Comment: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: What do those two URLs have to do with the code in the question?  Where are the server-side actions for those URLs?  Nobody here can see what you're not showing us, you have to provide information about the problem.

Comment: Get rid of `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` and just use: `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]`

Answer (score 0):

So your Ajax request is looking for an action named _sendConfirmation on your Mails controller and not finding it but you've chose. To just show us your home controller index action so we have no idea if the appropriate controller exists or not with that.

As far as having it decorated with a get and a post, when you do this you are essentially telling the action to look for data on the request in two different places which will most likely not end well for you unless you plan on doing that switch logic yourself inside the action. Your code would probably be a bit less error prone if you seperated the action and once extracted the data, you call the same helper methods to work your data.